# Trying to get Jasmine to work with Webpack

Tags: typescript, webpack, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I'm trying to migrate a project from tsc to webpack so I can bundle all the scripts. Right now, I'm running into an issue with Jasmine: TS2304: Cannot find name 'describe'. Here's my karma config:

```
module.exports = function(config) {

  var appBase    = 'app/';       // transpiled app JS and map files
  var appSrcBase = 'app/';       // app source TS files
  var appAssets  = '/base/app/'; // component assets fetched by Angular's compiler

  // Testing helpers (optional) are conventionally in a folder called `testing`
  var testingBase    = 'testing/'; // transpiled test JS and map files
  var testingSrcBase = 'testing/'; // test source TS files

  config.set({
    basePath: '',
    frameworks: ['jasmine'],

    plugins: [
      require('karma-jasmine'),
      require('karma-chrome-launcher'),
      require('karma-jasmine-html-reporter')
    ],

    client: {
      builtPaths: [appBase, testingBase], // add more spec base paths as needed
      clearContext: false // leave Jasmine Spec Runner output visible in browser
    },

    customLaunchers: {
      // From the CLI. Not used here but interesting
      // chrome setup for travis CI using chromium
      Chrome_travis_ci: {
        base: 'Chrome',
        flags: ['--no-sandbox']
      }
    },

    files: [
      // System.js for module loading
      'node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js',

      // Polyfills
      'node_modules/core-js/client/shim.js',

      // zone.js
      'node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js',
      'node_modules/zone.js/dist/long-stack-trace-zone.js',
      'node_modules/zone.js/dist/proxy.js',
      'node_modules/zone.js/dist/sync-test.js',
      'node_modules/zone.js/dist/jasmine-patch.js',
      'node_modules/zone.js/dist/async-test.js',
      'node_modules/zone.js/dist/fake-async-test.js',

      // RxJs
      { pattern: 'node_modules/rxjs/**/*.js', included: false, watched: false },
      { pattern: 'node_modules/rxjs/**/*.js.map', included: false, watched: false },

      // Paths loaded via module imports:
      // Angular itself
      { pattern: 'node_modules/@angular/**/*.js', included: false, watched: false },
      { pattern: 'node_modules/@angular/**/*.js.map', included: false, watched: false },

      { pattern: 'systemjs.config.js', included: false, watched: false },
      'karma-test-shim.js', // optionally extend SystemJS mapping e.g., with barrels

      // transpiled application & spec code paths loaded via module imports
      { pattern: appBase + '**/*.js', included: false, watched: true },
      { pattern: testingBase + '**/*.js', included: false, watched: true },


      // Asset (HTML & CSS) paths loaded via Angular's component compiler
      // (these paths need to be rewritten, see proxies section)
      { pattern: appBase + '**/*.html', included: false, watched: true },
      { pattern: appBase + '**/*.css', included: false, watched: true },

      // Paths for debugging with source maps in dev tools
      { pattern: appSrcBase + '**/*.ts', included: false, watched: false },
      { pattern: appBase + '**/*.js.map', included: false, watched: false },
      { pattern: testingSrcBase + '**/*.ts', included: false, watched: false },
      { pattern: testingBase + '**/*.js.map', included: false, watched: false}
    ],

    // Proxied base paths for loading assets
    proxies: {
      // required for component assets fetched by Angular's compiler
      "/app/": appAssets
    },

    exclude: [],
    preprocessors: {},
    reporters: ['progress', 'kjhtml'],
    webpack: require('./webpack.config.js'),

    port: 9876,
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
    autoWatch: true,
    browsers: ['Chrome'],
    singleRun: false
  })
}
```

Here's my webpack config:

```
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  entry: ["./src/ts/main.ts","./src/ts/css.ts"],
  module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /\.ts$/,
          loaders: [
            {
              loader: 'awesome-typescript-loader',
              options: { configFileName: 'tsconfig.json' }
            } , 'angular2-template-loader'
          ]
        },
        {
          test: /\.jsx$/,
          use: "babel-loader"
        },
        {
          test: /\.html$/,
          use: "html-loader"
        },
        {
          test: /\.css$/,
          use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({use: 'css-loader'})
        },
        {
          test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg)$/i,
          use: ['url-loader?limit=10000', 'img-loader']
        },
        {
          test: /\.(eot|woff2?|ttf)$/i,
          use: 'url-loader'
        }
      ]
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: [".tsx", ".ts", ".js"]
  },
  plugins: [
    new ExtractTextPlugin("public/styles.css"),
  ],
  output: {
    filename: "public/bundle.js"
  }
}
```

I'm getting no where on this. The help I've found so far just gives me either "Cannot find name" or "Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in" errors.

Comment: have you installed type for jasmin and declared it in your tsconfig file like this "types": ["jasmine"]

Comment: I did, it compiles just fine if I only use tsc, but I need webpack to merge all the script.

Answer (score 2):

You need to install type for jasmin

```
npm i --save-dev @types/jasmine
```

and then declare it in your tsconfig file

```
"types": ["jasmine"]
```

Comment: "karma start" still won't run webpack and the webpack command still gives the "TS2304: Cannot find name 'describe'" error.